# How to implement a post increment macro in Rust

Tags: rust

Is it possible to implement a post increment macro in Rust?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut i = 0usize;
    let v = vec!(0,1,2,3,);
    println!("{}", post_inc!(i)); // 0
    println!("{}", post_inc!(i)); // 1
    // i = 3
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! This is pretty easy:

```rust
macro_rules! post_inc {
    ($i:ident) => { // the macro is callable with any identifier (eg. a variable)
        { // the macro evaluates to a block expression
            let old = $i; // save the old value
            $i += 1; // increment the argument
            old // the value of the block is `old`
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let mut i = 0usize;
    let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
    println!("{}", post_inc!(i)); // 0
    println!("{}", post_inc!(i)); // 1
                                  // i = 3
}
```

[(Permalink to the playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bca1eb0e9b39c02981c83c9201260b87)

Comment: This macro can also easily be expanded to work with arbitrary mutable expressions as well: [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7c09c723155110b76748d34de897355c).